# How can I achieve this CSS in a fluid layout?

Tags: css, fluid-layout, ionic-framework

I've built a UI of a loop of cards however I'm struggling to make the UI work for a fluid screen layout. Can anyone suggest how I could arrange a series of divs into an outer container that can vary in heights and widths? To make things a little easier the container will always follow a portrait dimension.

I've also added a jsFiddle link to allow you to try editing the html / css.

http://jsfiddle.net/w2we2gyd/

```
<div class="card-preview">
    <p>1</p>
    <div class='circle'></div>
    <div class='card-preview-top'></div>
    <div class='card-preview-bottom'></div>
</div>
```

[image: Layout screenshot]

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ I can however it's quite bulky. I'll add it and you can let me know if it helps.

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ Revised the question, now contains a sample jsFiddle and markup.

Comment: You are doing most thinds with `%` anyway, so why not add `height: 100%;` to your `html,body` and then make your container `100%` and your cards '29%' in `height`. Then centering the number is a matter of using relative position for outer boxes, absolute for inner ones with `left: 50%;` and `top: 50%;` and then using `transform: translate(-50%,-50%)` to center the bugger.

Answer (score 0):

First off: I'm not a fan of how your CSS is laid out, try to use a preprocessor to structure your code and then just output it regularly. Apart from that, adding the following lines does, make it responsive:

```
.card-preview p {
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  right: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.loop-container{
    height:100%;
}

.loop-status, .card-preview {
  height: 29%;
}
```

```css
/* Loop container could be variable widths / height */
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
.loop-container
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.loop-status, .card-preview {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 5px 5px 5px;
  width: 29%;
  height: 29%;
  background: #fff; }

.loop-status .circle, .card-preview .circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 75%;
  height: 45%;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  background-color: white;
  left: 0;
  border: solid 4px #00b9aa;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto; }
  .loop-status .circle i, .card-preview .circle i {
    display: none; }
  .loop-status .circle.loop-correct, .card-preview .circle.loop-correct {
    background-color: #00b9aa; }
    .loop-status .circle.loop-correct i, .card-preview .circle.loop-correct i {
      display: inline;
      margin: auto;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: block;
      color: white;
      font-size: 50px;
      padding: 10px; }
  .loop-status .circle.loop-incorrect, .card-preview .circle.loop-incorrect {
    background-color: #A23842; }
    .loop-status .circle.loop-incorrect i, .card-preview .circle.loop-incorrect i {
      display: inline;
      margin: auto;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      display: block;
      color: white;
      font-size: 50px;
      padding: 10px; }

.card-preview {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: solid 4px #00b9aa;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease; }
  .card-preview:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
    -o-transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.05, 1.05);
    transform: scale(1.05, 1.05); }
  .card-preview p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #00534c;
    font: 25px/105px sans serif;
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 3;
    line-height: 6.5em; }
  .card-preview.current .card-preview-top {
    -webkit-animation: pulsate 2s infinite;
    -moz-animation: pulsate 2s infinite;
    -o-animation: pulsate 2s infinite;
    -ms-animation: pulsate 2s infinite;
    animation: pulsate 2s infinite; }
  .card-preview.answered .card-preview-top {
    background-color: white; }
  .card-preview.hinted .card-preview-top {
    -webkit-animation: pulsateError 2s infinite;
    -moz-animation: pulsateError 2s infinite;
    -o-animation: pulsateError 2s infinite;
    -ms-animation: pulsateError 2s infinite;
    animation: pulsateError 2s infinite; }
  .card-preview .card-preview-top {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: #727272;
    z-index: 1; }
  .card-preview .card-preview-bottom {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    background-color: #00b9aa;
    z-index: 1; }

/* Added code below */

.card-preview p {
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  right: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.loop-container{
    height:100%;
}

.loop-status, .card-preview {
  height: 29%;
}
```

```html
<div class='loop-container'>
<div class="card-preview">
    <p>1</p>
    <div class='circle'></div>
    <div class='card-preview-top'></div>
    <div class='card-preview-bottom'></div>
</div>
<div class="card-preview">
    <p>2</p>
    <div class='circle'></div>
    <div class='card-preview-top'></div>
    <div class='card-preview-bottom'></div>
</div>
<div class="card-preview">
    <p>3</p>
    <div class='circle'></div>
    <div class='card-preview-top'></div>
    <div class='card-preview-bottom'></div>
</div>
<div class="card-preview">
    <p>4</p>
    <div class='circle'></div>
    <div class='card-preview-top'></div>
    <div class='card-preview-bottom'></div>
</div>
<!-- Cards should appear in a loop with an empty middle -->
<div class="loop-status" class='overview'>
</div>
<div class="card-preview">
    <p>5</p>
    <div class='circle'></div>
    <div class='card-preview-top'></div>
    <div class='card-preview-bottom'></div>
</div>
<div class="card-preview">
    <p>6</p>
    <div class='circle'></div>
    <div class='card-preview-top'></div>
    <div class='card-preview-bottom'></div>
</div>
<div class="card-preview">
    <p>7</p>
    <div class='circle'></div>
    <div class='card-preview-top'></div>
    <div class='card-preview-bottom'></div>
</div>
<div class="card-preview">
    <p>8</p>
    <div class='circle'></div>
    <div class='card-preview-top'></div>
    <div class='card-preview-bottom'></div>
</div>
</div>
```

The only issue is that you want a margin in pixels, well, you can solve this in the following way:

```
.loop-status, .card-preview {
    /* non-calc supporting fallback */
    height: 29%;
    /* calc supporting browsers will do this right */
    height: calc(100% / 3 - 15px);
    width: 29%;
    width: calc(100% / 3 - 10px);
    margin: 2%;
    margin: calc(10px) calc(5px) calc(5px) calc(5px);
}
```

Comment: I had to take the output CSS that was produced from SCSS compilation which is why it wasn't ideally formatted.

Comment: @brianscott Hmm, you oughta change your CSS output then :) I find this strange to look at. But thats no matter.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Also, there's a tidy up button at the top of jsFiddle that reformats everything conveniently just in case you weren't aware. :-)

Comment: @brianscott Actually I wasn't :) Did this answer help you?